# ECM voltage, spark spike

Tags: pontiac, electronic-control-module, solstice, solstice-of-sorrow, voltage

When the car was idling in the garage this morning (hooked up to HP Tuners), I saw a spike on the "Spark" graph at the same time as the car stumbled. "Control Module Voltage" also went from > 14 down to 13.69. Not a *massive* difference, but I don't know what the operating range for the computer is, so I can't tell if that's a real problem. It's weird that voltage would drop, though.

RPM also dropped from 850 down to about 740, then came back up.

Here's the chart:[image]

It did this twice more over the course of about 10 minutes.

Comment: This is on your Solstice?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes. And now I'm getting a p0107 (MAP sensor)

Comment: When are you just going to drive that thing off a cliff? :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 very very soon. :(

Comment: @Paulster2 And I have apparently managed to ruin my MAP sensor. Now it shoes only 1.2PSI always. Car runs fine until I rev it, then it stumbles and dies. Start it again -stumbles and tries to die, reset codes (while running) and everything runs fine, util I rev it again. WTF.

Comment: Bank 2 fuel trims maxed out(!)  Is there any reason for that you may know of off the top of your head?

Comment: @Zshoulders It's an inline 4cylinder. The Bank2 stuff shouldn't even be on the screen. That is the default layout in HP Tuners, probably intended for V's.

Comment: @ David Lively ah of course, there is no bank 2.  woops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this off the unanswered question list:

There was an intermittent break in the wiring harness near the MAP sensor. I removed the damaged section and [lineman-spliced](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/48895/can-i-connect-wires-by-just-twisting-them-together-and-insulating-with-tape/48900) it, and this particular problem disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

That is a lot of spark advance.  It looks like its sitting at 5-7ish degrees, then pulls up to almost 30 suddenly.  Thats way higher than any normal adjustment I've seen.

[image: his data with a line added]
I added my own line onto your graph, and it looks like the voltage drop coincides with the start of the spark advance.  Based on this, the fact that the MAP is suddenly blown, and the stalking I did on some of your previous questions where you mention sticky valves... It sounds like it could be a misfire that went back into the intake instead of out the exhuast.  That could/would blow your MAP and maybe set off the knock sensor (which would violently pull timing, as we see here).

But those are pretty rare from my understanding.  Maybe it was just a Gremlin.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this car have two MAP sensors?  See [this discussion forum](http://www.skyroadster.com/forums/f24/code-p0107-80393/) for more information.  Seems like one of them involves temperature, so you may have replace them as a pair.

Comment: No. One MAP, one MAF with integrated IAT.

Comment: The GXP (LNF 2.0L factory turbo) has two MAPS, but my car is a 2.4L with aftermarket turbo. Good call, though.,